# WordPress: Convert array full of image ID's into src via for loop

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I have an array which is comprises of image ID's:

`$exp_gallery = [];`

A `print_r($exp_gallery)` prints `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 168 [1] => 59 [2] => 166 ) )`

I'm trying to convert those ID's into actual images so I'm running:

```
foreach($exp_gallery as $id){
     $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');
     echo '<img src="' . esc_url($img[0]) . '" />';
}
```

But when inspecting the code, it shows the following markup `<img src="(unknown)">` and only one `<img>` element is found. There's three items in my array so I, at the very least, am looking to see three `<img>` elements?

Comment: `foreach($exp_gallery[0] as $id)`

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code.

```
foreach($exp_gallery as $ids){
    foreach($ids as $id){
         $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');
         echo '<img src="' . esc_url($img[0]) . '" />';
    }
}
```